# htaccess - redirect only sub domain http to https

Tags: apache, url-rewrite-module

I want to redirect http to https with `.htaccess` rewrite_mod only pages under one subdomain.

for example: only for this sub domain: **http://www.test.com/product/**

**http**://www.test.com/product/good1/    to      **https**://www.test.com/product/good1/

from **http**://www.test.com/product/good2/    to      **https**://www.test.com/product/good2/

**the question is: is it possible? if yes, could you give me one example?**

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` only contain domain names like `www.test.com`. Your second condition won't work.